# Is there a way I can set the value of a pandas column to be a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to set the value in my pandas column to be equal to a dictionary. The value in my dictionary when I call it is for example: {'Foot': (4, 1)} or {'Ribs': (0, 1) ,'Collarbone': (8, 0)}. So the value of my dictionary is a dictionary too. So there are nested dictionaries.

I would like my pandas column to look like this:

```
Injuries
{'Foot': (4, 1)}
{'Ribs': (0, 1)}
```

Instead when I use iloc to set the value in the column it only gets set to:

```
Injuries
Foot
Ribs
```

How can I have the entire dictionary in the column as opposed to just the value?

Comment: That's not a nice way to store data in a DataFrame. The dictionaries will be of string type and not cleanly accessible. Could you not separate the key values from the dictionaries into their own columns?

Comment: I could but the problem is that the injury dictionary does not necessarily only have 1 injury. It could have a variable number of injuries. So I don't know how many columns I should keep. It could also look like this: {'Biceps': (0, 1), 'Concussion': (0, 1), 'Back': (0, 2)}

Comment: The values of your dictionary are tuples, do you always expect 2 elements, and what do they represent? `pandas` is really mean for 2D datasets. That being said, with a MultiIndex you can basically store any dimensionality you want.

Comment: Yes I always expect two elements in the tuples. The first one represents the games missed due to the injury and the second one represents the games the player played with an injury. So {'Foot': (4, 1)} would mean that the player missed 4 games with a foot injury and was injured for 1 game with a foot injury but played through it. Similarly, {'Ribs': (0, 1)} would mean the player did not miss any games with a rib injury but played through one game with a rib injury.